# How to prevent framework to jump into the .m file when crashing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using **XCode 6** to develop a SDK using static library. I grabbed the script from this link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios.

When I tried to crash it intentionally, the actual implementation is exposed. However, we wanted to hide it. Just like crashing a third party framework, for example Parse iOS SDK, it will jump to something like assembly code instead of the actual implementation file.

Here is image when crashing in Parse:
[image]

Any advances would be appreciate.

Comment: Could it be the case that you see the implementation because you haven't stripped debug symbols when building the framework and you have the source files of the framework in your project?

Comment: Those flags are set properly. And it still jumps to implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your setting is all correct, you can still see your implementation because you are using the same computer as you did development and being symbolicated automatically. It will be hidden when other users try to crash it.